# Javascript onclick display block issue

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Reaction Game</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"  />
  
 <style>
 
  body{
   background-color:#FFFFDB;
  }
  
  #container{
      font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
      border-radius: 20px;
      width:350px;
      margin:50px auto;
   height:150px;
      padding:auto;
   background-color:#CCFF99;
   display:block;
   
  } 
  #challenge{
   padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
   text-align:center;
   display:block;
  } 
  
  #container2{
      font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
      border-radius: 50px;
      width:450px;
   height:65px;
      margin:10px 0px 0px -53px;
      padding:auto;
   background-color:#00FFFF;
   position: absolute;
   display:block;
  }
  
  #instruction{
   padding:5px 5px 5px 10px;
   text-align:center;
   display:block;
   
  }
  
  #startGame{
      background-color: #CFDCE7;
      width:100px;
      height:40px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1em;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: transparent;
      color: #666666;
   position:center;
   text-align: center;
   -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-out;
   -moz-transition:all 1s ease-out;
   -ms-transition:all 1s ease-out;
   -o-transition:all 1s ease-out;
   transition:all 1s ease-out;
   margin-left:-30px;
   
   

     }
  #startGame:hover{
   background-color:red;
   font-size:150%;
   border-radius: 50px;
   width:200px;
   height;80px;
   font-weight:bold;
   -webkit-transform:scale(5);
   -moz-transform:scale(5);
   -ms-transform:scale(5);
   -o-transform:scale(5);
   transform:scale(5);
   position;center;
   
  } 
  
  #time {
  font-size:1.2em;
  font-family:arial;
  color:#333333;
  border:1px;
  border-style:dashed;
  width:280px;
  margin:auto;
  padding:auto;
  text-align:center;
  display:none;
  }
  
 </style>
 
 </head>
   
  <body>
   <div id="container">
    <div id="challenge"><h1>Are you up for the reaction challenge?</h1>
    <br/>
    <div id="container2">
    <div id="instruction"><p>Click on the boxes and circles as quickly as you can!</p><div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button id="startGame">Let's start</button>
   
   
   <div id="time">
   
    Your last try: <span id="tryTime">0</span>s</p>
    Best try: <span id="bestTime">0</span>s</p>
    Average Try: <span id="averageTime">0</span>s</p>
   
   </div>
   
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var container;
   var container2;
   var lasTry;
   var time;
   var startGame;
    
   document.getElementById("startGame").onclick=function() {
    document.getElementById("time").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("container").style.display="none";
   }
   
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

```
        document.getElementById("startGame").onclick=function() {
            document.getElementById("time").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("container").style.display="none";
        }
```

I cannot use onclick function to display div "time" after button "startGame" is pressed, if i do it other way to display none it works. please give me some tips where am i making a mistake cheers in advance!!!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think the real problem is your html your missing a few closing tags

Comment: I wouldn't do a getElementById on 'startGame' before being sure that the DOM is ready. Although the cause of your problem may be elsewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is the mass amount of closing div tags you're missing. Your `onClick` works but it adds none to the parent div of the whole page because that tag is not closed

```
document.getElementById("startGame").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("time").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("container").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="challenge">
    <h1>Are you up for the reaction challenge?</h1>
    <br/>
    <div id="container2">
      <div id="instruction">
        <p>Click on the boxes and circles as quickly as you can!</p>
        <div>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <button id="startGame">Let's start</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


          <div id="time">

            Your last try: <span id="tryTime">0</span>s</p>
            Best try: <span id="bestTime">0</span>s</p>
            Average Try: <span id="averageTime">0</span>s</p>

          </div>
```

If you close the top container tag before the **time** div it will add a **display none** to all elements within the tags

Answer (score 1):

Checked all your `<div>` tag close properly. I think you miss one `</div>` closing tag